# Specified forecast period not constraining forecast output

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am attempting to build an ARIMA model of a 10-year long time series, and use it to forecast one year into the future. To test my model, I train on 9 years of data, predict 1 year of data, and compare the predicted values to the actual values for that year.

**Problem**: I tell forecast() to constrain the period of its prediction to 365 i.e. 1 year. But when I plot the output, it appears to output 9 years or an "h=" of roughly 3285. Why is this occurring?

```
##The time series is 3650 daily observations of rainfall
x <- ts(x$obs, start=c(2007, 10), end=c(2017, 9), frequency = 365)

##create training set - first 9 years of observations
x_train <- subset(x, start = 1, end = 3285)

##test set - last year of observations
x_test <- subset(x, start = 3286, end = 3650)

##fit the model
x_train_fit <- auto.arima(x_train, seasonal=FALSE, xreg=fourier(x_train, K=1))

##forecast using the model 
x_fcast_test <- forecast(x_train_fit,h=365, xreg=fourier(x_train, K=1))
plot(x_fcast_test, col="black") 
lines(x_test,col="red")
```

[image]

**Update:** Rob Hyndman's answer below is correct. The number of forecast periods will be set to the number of rows of xreg because that is used in favor of h= when xreg is used, so my h= was not being used. Therefore, passing in the entire training set as an exreg created a forecast equal in length to the training set.

```
x_fcast_test <- forecast(x_train_fit,h=365, xreg=fourier(x_test, K=1))
plot(x_fcast_test, col="black") 
lines(x_test,col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always worth reading the help files that are provided. In this case:

> `h`:
>   Number of periods for forecasting. If `xreg` is used, `h` is ignored and the number of forecast periods is set to the number of rows of `xreg`.

You passed the training data in the `xreg` argument, so you get as many forecasts as you have observations.

Presumably you meant to use the test data for the `xreg` argument.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Thank you. Now I just need to determine why the forecast is poor and apparently even inverted...

Comment: Is there a way around this besides going into the object and extracting the data and cutting it shorter? I need my external regressors but I only want a length of period less than used to train the data in the first place. Thank you!